# Overriding the default tableview setEditing behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have currently implemented the setEditing/commitEditing methods for my table view, which now shows the 'delete' button upon swiping a cell.

Just wondering if there is any way to change the text on this button from 'delete' to something else, so that I can use the 'commitEditing' method to perform custom behaviour, such as update some settings?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the delete button title with the UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```